# Which later retellings of the MBh suggest that Shakuni's dice were made from Jarasandha's bones?

Tags: mahabharata, bhima, shakuni, jarasandha

I know this is a ridiculously niche question, but I'm at my wits' end, and any resource you could provide would help me immensely.

I'm working on a translation, and there's a throwaway comment that seems to suggest that a. Shakuni can make the dice do whatever he wants and b. Bhimasena as his opponent would prove to be the exception to that rule.

I did a little digging and I'm seeing COUNTLESS variations of the provenance of Sakuni's dice (which are super helpful for me), but, while I'm seeing loads of people comment that they grew up being told that Jarasandha's bones (i.e. the dice) quivered in fear whenever Bhimasena growled, which would mess with Sakuni's machinations, I can't find any traceable source for that which I could cite in my commentary.

So, if possible, I would like a text (in any language! I just need something!) that *proves* that this variation in the MBh's retellings exist.

It doesn't have to be from the 'original' MBh (I know it's not there, I'm combed over it and all the other interpolated versions with a fine tooth comb), but I just need *something* written down to demonstrate that this version of events does exist, and that some retellings do suggest that Jarasandha's bones were the material for the dice (and that this would be advantageous to Bhima).

Thank you so much in advance for your time and patience, and I look forward to hearing your responses.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to an extremely reliable source, [Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/608458802534509/photos/truth-behind-shakunis-dicethere-are-many-stories-surrounding-shakunis-dice-the-f/766009086779479/) (edited slightly):

> There are many stories surrounding Shakuni's dice. The first one is that the dice were made of his father's bones and his father's spirit resided in it thus following Shakuni's every order. The second is that he was a dark magician who infused the dice with magic. The third is that the dice had a magical creature (such as a beetle or a lizard) in that Shakuni had control over. **The fourth is from the Mrityunjaya, where Shakuni's dice were made from  Jarasandha's bones.** However, these stories are not mentioned in Vyasa's Mahabaratha and are added stories, folklore, or plain imagination.

I realize that the source is kind of (very) iffy, but I did a bit of extra research and it seems to check out. The [Mrityunjaya](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6369447) was a fairly well-known 1967 book written by Shivaji Sawant that chronicled the life of Karna. It's in Marathi, but you can download it [here](https://www.pdfdrive.com/mrutyunjay-e158370549.html). I didn't read the whole thing (it's 800+ pages), but I used the 'search in document function,' which yielded a couple dozen results for the names of Shakuni and Jarasandha. Presumably, this is where the story was first written down.

Edit: Here's a more reliable source that corroborates the fact from Facebook. [Pradip Bhattacharya writes in his analysis of the Mrityunjaya:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Shivaji_Sawant_s_Mrityunjaya/qO41AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)

> Yet another addition to epic data by Sawant for amplifying the role of Karna is the instruction given to Duhshasana to keep Karna away from the dice-game till it is over; **for the dice are made of Jarasndha's bones,** and they shiver at the sound of Karna's voice! In a southern recension of the Vishnu Purana the dice are said to be made from the skeleton of Shakuni's father, who had died in a Kaurava prison.

This supports the notion that this idea was first written down in the Mrityunjaya. However, I doubt that this was where the story *originated*, it is likely from earlier folktales and folk retellings. that Sawant happened to have recorded in his version. I hope that this helps you, and maybe someone else will be able to use this and find an earlier citation.